# ZOHO CRM - How to find and merge all the duplicate records in bulk?

Tags: zoho

I am working in Zoho Crm. I have many duplicates records in **Account**. Is it possible to find and merge all the duplicate records at once.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far my knowledge for now, Currently there is not any possible way by which it can be possible to merge all the duplicate records in bulk in ZOHO CRM.
The only way to merge it one by one by click on find and merge. but not in bulk.

you have to get it done manually. All the best